# Rewording the source and destination locations labels

Tags: buttons

We are developing a carpooling app, the app needs to support a `FROM` and `TO` location. We are first asking for `TO` rather than first asking for `FROM`. I am wondering if the labels can be better worded or can the dropdowns be better designed to save space along the length to make it look less cluttered.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Where are you going?" and "Now, I am at" are a curious mixture of "speakers". First, the app asks me, then I talk back to it... Resulting from this, one is a question, and one is a statement. I'd consolidate this in any case.

I (personally) would not simulate a dialog with the app. So I would not use questions. This leaves "I want to go to " and "Go to " as alternatives.

To shorten reading, I'd choose "Go to" and "Start from", preventing the complexity of complete sentences. (Do you need this translated as well? Sentence order differs and may pose problems since the location must be the last sentence part, and may sound awkward in some languages.)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple start with where the user is located and then where they want to go. "I am located at..." and "I want to go to...". The entire screen can be better designed, there seems to be no map or GPS functionality to aid the user. You've assumed that all your users will prefer lists over maps.

Comment: Yes, this is not a anywhere to anywhere carpool app. Its a specific market segment.

Comment: In that instance then a drop down list will be fine.

Comment: I am not sure that it would be better to ask for where someone is first. When planning a journey, one usually is more interested in the destination. The current location is only interesting for others that help the planning. When I am in Amsterdam and want to go to Maastricht, I am more interested to find Maastricht on a map and work back from there.